# Xcode 11 beta: AppDelegate file doesn't have window global variable

Tags: xcode, uikit, appdelegate, uiwindow

I am facing an issue in Xcode 11 beta.

The problem is that I am not getting default `window` variable declared in `AppDelegate` file.

Is anybody facing this same issue?

Comment: What issue is this causing you?

Comment: I am using Xcode 11 beta, simply I created single view application. In AppDelegate file there is no object call window. Whereas we had it during previous Xcode versions.

Comment: And again, what problem is this causing you?

Comment: I want to use window variable to set rootViewController. Does that make sense?

Comment: `UIApplicationDelegate` already defines the `window` property. `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window`.

Comment: Ok, let me check

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 11 this is now done in SceneDelegate

EDIT: if you’re still supporting iOS 12 or prior (or want to support 13 plus prior)

Add the `UIWindowSceneDelegate` to `ApplicationDelegate`

Add : `var window:UIWindow?`

Then proceed as you would to setting up in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: Yes, but what if your new project's target is iOS11 or iOS12? That line needs to be in `AppDelegate` then.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

The default var window: UIWindow? Is now moved in SceneDelegate.swift. To set a rootViewController in Xcode 11 you can work within SceneDelegate.swift file, In the scene delegate, you must create the window instance and the root view controller like below:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        // set or create your viewController here
        let yourViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "yourViewController") as! YourViewController
        // set the rootViewController here using window instance
        self.window?.rootViewController = yourViewController
    }
```

Also this answer is helpful : [Why is manually setup root view controller showing black screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451496/why-is-manually-setup-root-view-controller-showing-black-screen)

Hope it will help you!

Comment: This function can only be used in iOS 13 as it write

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

first, in AppDelegate create a static property with the class of the view controller you want to access, like this

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // MARK: Home
    static var homeViewController: HomeViewController?

    ...
}
```

then, in the view controller

```
// MARK: - Managing the view
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Singleton
    AppDelegate.homeViewController = self

    ...
}
```

how to use:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var homeViewController: HomeViewController? {
        if let controller = self as? HomeViewController {
            return controller
        }

        return AppDelegate.homeViewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, that's all it takes.

```
    var window: UIWindow? // add this by yourself
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: Device.bounds)
        let root = DDTabBarController()
        window?.rootViewController = root
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```