# Instantiate initial UIViewController in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, appdelegate

I know, there are a lot of similar threads but I'm still struggling to get this problem solved.

I want to instantiate a certain viewcontroller in AppDelegate (only if a user is not logged in). But even without an authentication check my code in app delegate to instantiate my login controller seems to be ignored:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let loginController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginController") as! LoginController
        self.window!.rootViewController = loginController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return true
    }
}
```

No matter which view controller I instantiate in app delegate, the initial view controller set in storyboard appears when launching my app. (Note: if no view controller is set as initial in storyboard, the app is launching with a black screen).
What's my mistake?

Thanks a lot in advance
Alex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57451496/6576315

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method --

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialVC: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
     let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialVC)
    navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a modern iOS app, the app delegate has no window. You can create one but it will be replaced. The visible window belongs to the *scene delegate*. You need to create the interface using scene delegate code.

Comment: For an example, see https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample.